# Symfony Monolog's IntrospectionProcessor logging after a FingersCrossedHandler Q&A

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

In monolog's fingers_crossed handler, the log records are held back until a certain level triggers to unload/show all those with-held records. So far, so good.

When those withheld messages are dumped after a fingers_crossed trigger, you may now actually want to know all the source lines. (And NOT before the fingers_crossed). For this the IntrospectionProcessor is used - but, as its creator specifies: 'Warning: This only works if the handler processes the logs directly. If you put the processor on a handler that is behind a FingersCrossedHandler for example, the processor will only be called once the trigger level is reached, and all the log records will have the same file/line/.. data from the call that triggered the FingersCrossedHandler.' - not good!.

This issue was raised for the 'Laravel 5' similar issue, without a satisfying answer. Here I present a working Symfony (2/3) solution.

src/AppBundle/IntrospectionPreprocessor.php:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle;

class IntrospectionPreprocessor    // ATTENTION TO THE 'PRE'
      extends \Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor  // SO USE THE ORIGINAL CLASS
{
    public function processRecord(array $record)
    {
        return $this( $record );  // CALL TO ITS __INVOKE(..)
    }
}
```

The services.logger.yml:

```
services:
  monolog.processor.introspection_patch:
    class:          AppBundle\IntrospectionPreprocessor
    arguments:      [ DEBUG, [Helper, Google] ]    # FILTER OUT CLASSES THAT CONTAIN [..], similar to IntrospectionProcessor
    tags:
      - { name: monolog.processor, method: processRecord }
```

This now inserts the correct file/line/class/function info, AFTER fingers_crossed triggers subsequent handlers.

Q. Is there a way to properly make this a part of my Symfony framework, so not in my application area (AppBundle), but neither touching the Symfony code (eg. gets lost with an upgrade?)